# Going Mobile: Converting a Java Project With multiple Classes into one Class as to port To WP8

Tags: c#, java, datetime, windows-phone-8, jodatime

I am working on modifying org.joda.time to be simplified to be exclusively a calendar converter for the Coptic calendar. Quite simply This is an example of the extent of information I would like to develop an app around:

```
package src.example.org.joda.example.time;


import org.joda.time.DateTime;
 import org.joda.time.chrono.CopticChronology;


class Age{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        DateTime dtISO = new DateTime(2013, 9, 6, 23, 12);


        DateTime Copt = dtISO.withChronology(CopticChronology.getInstance());

        String Result=Copt.toString();
        String[] Result2 = Result.split("T");
        System.out.println(Result2[0] + "\n");
        System.out.println(Result2[1]);
}
        }
```

Which produces the following output:

1729-13-01

23:12:00.000-04:00

Is there any way to remove all the unnecessary clutter so I can more easily port this to WP8? Thanks, Beshoy Hanna.

**UPDATE: NodaTime is the .NET port of JodaTime /facepalm.**

Comment: Have you tried [Noda-time](https://code.google.com/p/noda-time/) ?

Comment: I have not. Sounds Interesting, I will update if I get it working. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Comparable code for the above is as follows:

> using NodaTime.Calendars;
>
> using NodaTime;
>
> namespace CopticCalendar {
>
> ```
> public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
> {
>     // Constructor
>     public MainPage()
>     {
>         InitializeComponent();
>     }
> ```

```
 private void NodaTime(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
     
     LocalDateTime DateToConvertFrom = new LocalDateTime(2014, 9, 6, 23, 12, 0);
  
     CalendarSystem CoptCal = CalendarSystem.GetCopticCalendar(1);
 
     String ConvertedTime = Convert.ToString(DateToConvertFrom.WithCalendar(CoptCal));

     String[] ConvertedTimeF=ConvertedTime.Split();

     YearTextBox.Text = String.Format(ConvertedTimeF[0].ToString() + "\n\n" + ConvertedTimeF[1].ToString());

 }
```